# Ruby equivalent of `GOTO` in BASIC

Tags: ruby

I built a mainmenu with the individual points leading to submenus. I want to let the user jump from a submenu to the mainmenu. In BASIC, this is possible with GOTO, in other languages I would load a module and put a new link. What do I do in Ruby? I am looking for an equivalent to GOTO.

Comment: GOTO doesn't exist in modern languages.  I suppose that you should show us what you've got so far, and we'll be able to help you from there.

Comment: I'm guessing each of your menus consists of some code that displays a menu and asks the user for a choice? In that case you could define a function for each menu. That way the program will automatically jump back.

Comment: Ruby doesn't come with a `GOTO` equivalent by default. While it's possible to [add `GOTO` through a Gem (a Ruby library)](https://rubygems.org/gems/goto) or [by recompiling MRI with not-so-serious compile options](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/2/29/the-joke-is-on-us-how-ruby-1-9-supports-the-goto-statement), believe me that **this. Is. Not. What. You. Want.** Instead, make yourself familiar with [structured programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming). If you feel you need `GOTO`, [you're doing it wrong](https://www.xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: thanks das-g and @SpiderPig, that was useful!

Comment: Only old people truly understand the evil that was embodied in `GOTO`.

Comment: It doesn't take being old to understand it, it just takes reading the arguments against it or using a language that supports it long enough to have encountered spaghetti code.